# Java generics ? extends Clazz

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, junit4

I'm using spring, hibernate and junit to setup a test class for some of my models.

All of my models extend **BaseModel**

I have the following function in my testing class:

```
void printValidation(Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends BaseModel>> v){
        Iterator<ConstraintViolation<? extends BaseModel>> it = v.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ConstraintViolation<? extends BaseModel> violation = it.next();
            l.info("Validation error {}", violation);
        }
    }
```

I use it like so inside a test case:

```
eModel = new Entry(); //This class extends BaseModel
Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends BaseModel>> v = validator.validate(eModel);
assertTrue("There should be validation errors...", v.size() > 0);
printValidation(v);
```

However, I get the following message in Eclipse, and it does not seem to work:  Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Set<ConstraintViolation<Entry>>` to `Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends BaseModel>>`

I have a bunch of other tests, and if I make the function take `<Entry>` instead of `<? extends BaseEntry>` it works.  I have a number of models I'm testing like this, and it is sort of the whole point of generics to not have to duplicate this.

What am I missing here, I guess it has something to do with either what validator.validate is returning or something?

** Edited to fix inline code formatting **

Answer (score 1):

@geoand - Almost, here is the working code:

```
<T extends BaseModel> void printValidation(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> v){
    Iterator<ConstraintViolation<T>> it = v.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ConstraintViolation<T> violation = it.next();
        l.info("Validation error {}", violation);
    }
}
```

And the function that does the test:

```
@Test
public void testEntry() {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Entry>> v = validator.validate(eModel);
    assertTrue("There should be validation errors...", v.size() > 0);
    printValidation(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `void <T extends BaseModel> printValidation(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> v)`

Comment: I updated my answer in order to not confuse future viewers of the question. Thanks for the comment